# listView items are repeating and becoming more each time app runs

Tags: java, android, listview

I am implementing a sample app for android and in the list view I don't use view holder so I couldn't get my answer from other answers. my list view items are repeating and becoming more each time I run the app unless I uninstall the app from emulator.
here is my code where in the first class I declare the list view and set adapter and the next class is the customized adapter(I removed unnecessary functions):

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView crimesListView;
    private CrimeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View CrimesList=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list,container,false);
       crimesListView=(ListView) CrimesList.findViewById(R.id.crimesList);
       adapter=new CrimeAdapter(inflater.getContext(),R.layout.list_item_crime,CrimeLab.get(inflater.getContext()).getCrimes());
       crimesListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
public class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context _context;
    List<Crime> _crimes;
    static Crime currentCrime;
    public CrimeAdapter( Context context, int resource,  List crimes) {
        super(context, resource, crimes);
        _context=context;
        _crimes=crimes;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View _convertView = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (_convertView == null)
            _convertView= ((Activity)_context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime,null);

         currentCrime=_crimes.get(position);
          ((TextView)_convertView.findViewById(R.id.crimeTitleText)).setText(currentCrime.getTitle().toString());
        ((TextView)_convertView.findViewById(R.id.crimeDateText)).setText(currentCrime.getCrimeDate().toString());
        ((ImageView)_convertView.findViewById(R.id.crimeImageSolved)).setVisibility(currentCrime.getSolved() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);


       return _convertView;
    }
    public void setCrimes(List<Crime> crimes){
        _crimes=crimes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post ur output screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
_convertView= ((Activity)_context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime,null);
```

to

```
_convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `CrimeListFragment` code with below snippet. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView crimesListView;
    private CrimeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View CrimesList=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list,container,false);
       crimesListView=(ListView) CrimesList.findViewById(R.id.crimesList);
       List<Crime> _crimes = new ArrayList();
       _crimes.clear();
       _crimes = CrimeLab.get(inflater.getContext()).getCrimes();
       adapter=new CrimeAdapter(inflater.getContext(),R.layout.list_item_crime, _crimes);
       crimesListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
public class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context _context;
    List<Crime> _crimes;
    static Crime currentCrime;
    public CrimeAdapter( Context context, int resource,  List crimes) {
        super(context, resource, crimes);
        _context=context;
        _crimes=crimes;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View _convertView = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (_convertView == null)
            _convertView= ((Activity)_context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime,null);

         currentCrime=_crimes.get(position);
          ((TextView)_convertView.findViewById(R.id.crimeTitleText)).setText(currentCrime.getTitle().toString());
        ((TextView)_convertView.findViewById(R.id.crimeDateText)).setText(currentCrime.getCrimeDate().toString());
        ((ImageView)_convertView.findViewById(R.id.crimeImageSolved)).setVisibility(currentCrime.getSolved() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);


       return _convertView;
    }
    public void setCrimes(List<Crime> crimes){
        _crimes=crimes;
    }
}
```